# Embed resulting Google document in iFrame

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

I am trying to embed the resulting document in an iFrame for the user (already authenticated) to continue editing:

```
// init client
gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(() => {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus());

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    });
});

function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    signedIn = isSignedIn;
}

// sign in
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();

// get documents
function retrieveDoc() {
    gapi.client.docs.documents.get({
        documentId: 'abcd-1234'
    }).then(function (response) {
        const doc = response.result;

        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?' +
            'authuser=0&amp;' +
            'srcid=' + doc.documentId + '&amp;' +
            'pid=explorer&amp;' +
            'a=v&amp;' +
            'chrome=false&amp;' +
            'embedded=true" height="1380" width="640"></iframe>';

        document.appendChild(iframe);
    }, function (response) {
        console.error(response);
    });
}
```

I am assuming it's because I'm not passing an `authuser` parameter, but what exactly would that be? `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()` does not return an id, so not entirely sure how I get this based off their current session. `gapi.auth2.GoogleUser` exists, but I cannot seem to do much with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Every session of using Google API you will need to use `gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth` to login on an account and does requires `gapi.auth2.GoogleUser` call. This will ensures that you will retrieve the information and check if the current user has authorized. Please see this [sample code](https://github.com/Fresiamay17/google-api-integration-app/blob/e3ac128aa08647d81d25241b1409d6c955304529/src/infrastructure/sessions/gapi.session.ts) flow.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I've authenticated already, this is retrieving a document of said user. I'll update question.